# Other ways to build a 2D map in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, textures, paintcomponent

as I'm new to java I thought of programming a simple 2D game where you can walk around in a 2D world which is made of 16x16 graphics. I already found a method to create textured JPanels:

```
public class TexturedPanel extends JPanel {
    private Image image;
    private boolean tile;

    TexturedPanel(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
        this.tile = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(tile) {
            int iw = image.getWidth(this);
            int ih = image.getHeight(this);
            if (iw > 0 && ih > 0) {
                for(int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += iw) {
                    for(int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y += ih) {
                        g.drawImage(image, x, y, iw, ih, this);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have to decide if I proceed with this method or if I should use another one...

So are there better (faster / more simple) methods to build a textured JPanel?

Thanks in advance, Marvin

Answer (score 1):

Note that the method you posted only tiles a single image. You would presumably want to tile multiple images.

One way to do this is by using a 2D array that contains the tile types of each grid cell, and then using that array to decide which image to draw at each grid cell.

I recommend starting out smaller- can you draw different colored rectangles based on a 2D array first?

Comment: Yes that won't be a problem (hope so ^^) I'm just wondering if that's a good way or if there's a better one. I planned to make it 2.5D so I need transparent images overlapping each other... is that possible to with this method?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "better" in this instance. I highly recommend just trying something out. Your approach seems pretty standard, so I wouldn't worry too much about it. But yes, it's possible to use transparent images using any of the approaches we've mentioned so far. Try it and find out for yourself- that's what makes programming fun!